# How close is English to Pali?

Tags: pali

How close is English to Pali? If you look at the etymological pages in wiktionary, for English words, it often includes a "Proto-Indo-European" root, and sometimes mentions Sanksrit too. Take e.g. 'mad'

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mad#Etymology

> From Middle English mad, madde, madd, medd, from Old English ġemǣdd,
> ġemǣded (“enraged”), past participle of ġemǣdan, *mǣdan (“to make
> insane or foolish”), from Proto-Germanic *maidijaną (“to change;
> damage; cripple; injure; make mad”), from Proto-Germanic *maidaz
> ("weak; crippled"; compare Old English gemād (“silly, mad”), Old High
> German gimeit (“foolish, crazy”), Gothic  (gamaiþs,
> “crippled”)), **from Proto-Indo-European *mey- ("to change"**; compare Old
> Irish máel (“bald, dull”), Old Lithuanian ap-maitinti (“to wound”),
> **Sanskrit मेथति (méthati, “he hurts, comes to blows”**)).

Is there anywhere I can read about Pali as a language that has influenced the etymon, development, of English today?

Answer (score 4):

You can find this info on the wikipedia page for [Indo-European Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages) in the form of a family tree below, with Pali and English highlighted with a yellow box.

Legend:

- Green: Language still in use
- Red: Language extinct
- White: Categories

English is a Germanic language, while Pali is an Indo-Iranian language. Both come under the major family of Indo-European languages.

[image: Indo-European Languages family tree]

Credits: Modified from [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages#/media/File:IndoEuropeanTree.svg)